# How do I set the focus of the list view on the last item in chat list

Tags: flutter

I have a list view where I show the chat list but when the list view always focus to the first item.

i set stack from bottom true in java and this work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try attach `ScrollController controller;` on  `ListView.builder()` and when to scroll use this

```
   controller.animateTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2), curve: Curves.easeIn);
```